# XMLHttpRequest: Cross origin requests are only supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

After I cleared chrome cookies&caches, I started getting XMLHttpRequest error when I click a link that its href is a javascript function. The link opens a [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo) and they are created in [a dojo ajax component](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/xhrGet.html) dynamically. When I click the link, I get `XMLHttpRequest` error.

`jquery-1.11.3.min.js:5 XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:sa(5). Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

I import DOJO in the `<header>`

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src='<c:url value="/resources/js/dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js" />'
    djConfig="parseOnLoad: true, usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false, async: false"></script>
```

and JQuery at the bottom of the `<body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src='<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />'></script>
```

The dynamic link `<a>`:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#roomModal" href="javascript:sa(5)">Deluxe Double Room</a>
```

JS function is in another file.

```
function sa(accommodationRoomId) {
    var modalHeader = document.getElementById("modalHeader");
    modalHeader.innerHTML += accommodationRoomId;
}
```

This error started showing up after I cleared chrome caches and cookies. What should I do to fix this error?

PS: The project is running on Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my function as

```
function sa(_this) {
    var modalBody = document.getElementById("modalBody");
    modalBody.innerHTML += "<span>"+_this.id+"</span>";
    console.log(_this);
}
```

and add `onclick` for `<a>`

```
<a data-toggle="modal" id="5" data-target="#roomModal" onclick="sa(this)">Deluxe Double Room</a>
```

Comment: It seems like using the `href` to run an AJAX request in a Javascript function makes it think it's some unsupported protocol or cross origin request. Changing it to the onclick fixes this behavior.